# Android - Calculator support all screen sizes

Tags: android, xml, calculator

I'm a beginner on android app developing and I have a problem which I cannot find any solution. I'm working the app on nexus 5 and it works perfect, no empty spaces between layouts, but when I switch to nexus 4, this is what happens ( i am using colors to separate the layouts) :

https://scontent.fath3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/20403684_1379424475444386_454511879_n.jpg?oh=440d7b9ab5670c8cad87133475ec0cb6&oe=5979CDED

if i switch to pixel xl :

https://scontent.fath3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/20403737_1379426118777555_859609190_n.jpg?oh=61ccd01da7a4470491fb4125da8db43c&oe=597996E4

What can i do so it doesn't have any empty spaces on the right?(below there is XML code posted just in case you need it).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f00">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="onClickDTB"
            android:text="Convert to Binary"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0f0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="98dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
            android:text="Calculator"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout


    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="72.4dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFA500"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="72.4dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000FFF"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="72.4dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#8B0000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="72.4dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#800080"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="72.4dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#2E8B57"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: Use weight and weight Sum property for you layout

Comment: I've seen every link available and i've tried it but it seems that it's not working. That's why i asked i need someone to explain the problem based on my code so i understand what happens in general.

Comment: weight sum is already used, it is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Must use weight and weight Sum like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f00">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="onClickDTB"
            android:text="Convert to Binary"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0f0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="98dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
            android:text="Calculator"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout


        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f0f"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFA500"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000FFF"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#8B0000"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#800080"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#2E8B57"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: oh, i see...same answer, which means it is the way to do it

Comment: Yes layout weight will divide you parent layout to 5 portion's which cover you screen fully and No right space left .

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f00">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="onClickDTB"
        android:text="Convert to Binary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#0f0">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="98dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="Calculator"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFA500"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000FFF"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#8B0000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#800080"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#2E8B57"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so you actually added layout_weight to all layouts?

Comment: Yes  @A.Tressos, you need to add if it needs to fit with all screen sizes.